# EventListener function error: CSS manipulation via vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an error that my eventlistener is not a function.  I've search previous threads/ documentation but have not been able to find an answer to my specific issue.  The goal is to manipulate border-top-left-radius when a user inputs a number in the text box. I'm very new to javascript so it is possible that I'm not using it correctly.

HTML:

```
<div id="topLeftBorder" > Top Left <br>
      <input type="number" id="inputTL" value="0" min ="1" max="100"> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var inputTL = document.getElementById('inputTL').value + 'px';
console.log(inputTL);


var borderPreview = document.getElementById('borderPreview');
var currentRadius = borderPreview.style.borderTopLeftRadius;
console.log(currentRadius);

inputTL.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (inputTL !== "0px") {
    currentRadius = tLBorderChange;
  }
});
```

I receive the correct values at my console.logs but when the function runs it returns the error. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `inputTL` is a string, not an element, don't try to `addEventListener` to a string

Comment: If I have it return a number (ie do not add the +"px") it still returns the same error.  Does this mean that input number being returned is a string?

Comment: Yes input.value is always a string, but even if it were a number the problem would be the same. You want the Element (`document.getElementById('inputTL')`)

Comment: I see. How do I iterate through the element to get the value to change since it will return an array of the input tag?

Comment: You should know that you cannot get JavaScript Element.style properties unless you've already set them in JavaScript. Use `getComputedStyle(borderPreview).borderTopLeftRadius`. Just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

(1) Call `addEventListener` on the element, not the string (calling it on a string won't work)

(2) To set the style, you have to explicitly assign to a `style` object; reassigning a variable name alone (like `currentRadius`) will not have any side effects:

```
var inputTL = document.getElementById('inputTL');
var borderPreview = document.getElementById('borderPreview');

inputTL.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var tlValue = inputTL.value + 'px';
  if (tlValue !== "0px") {
    borderPreview.style.borderTopLeftRadius = tLBorderChange;
  }
});
```

It's a bit strange to concatenate `px` onto a string just to compare it against another string literal with `px` on it, consider instead:

```
  var tlValue = inputTL.value;
  if (tlValue !== "0") {
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It works!  I also took out the "px" comparison but added it back into the end so that the style was interpreted as px otherwise the function did not execute.  Again much appreciated.